# Not able to import geopandas after installation with anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, geopandas

I am trying to install geopandas on a clean environment using anaconda (Windows 10). This has worked properly in the past, but I encountered an error after reverting my base environment (where it was installed at the time) using `conda install --revision`. I have completely uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda since then, so I don't know how this could cause the problem.

I have followed the instructions from https://geopandas.org/install.html#installing-with-anaconda-conda and have tried both methods of installation using conda. The installation seems to run properly and there are no errors. When I then try to run `import geopandas as gpd` I get the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'`. I also checked `print('geopandas' in sys.modules)` which returns False. However, when I run `conda install geopandas` again I get the following message:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
All requested packages already installed.
```

When I run `conda remove geopandas`, a bunch of files are uninstalled, implying that they were in fact installed in the first place. I tried several suggestions made to similar posts with no luck. `conda config --env --set channel_priority strict`, `conda update -n base -c defaults conda`, even reinstalling spyder. I am currently using python 3.8, but the problem was not resolved when I tried a python 3.7.3 environment, which I know has worked for me in the past.

I know there are other ways to install geopandas, but I want to fix any possible issues with anaconda.

Edit: Spelling errors. More clarifying title.

Comment: Are you sure you are running python from the same environment?

Comment: As I mentioned, the environment is in python version 3.8. I tried running code that only uses numpy, pandas, and other standard packages in anaconda and they worked fine. I also tried uninstalling/reinstalling these packages and got no error.

Comment: Hi @Reigndeer, You may try creating an empty environment in conda, then activate that environment and then install your required package just to be sure. Hope this helps. https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands

Comment: Hi @user78910 , it might have been unclear in my post, but this is exactly what I am trying to do. I originally worked in the base environment, but wanted to move my work to a sepparate environment. After reinstalling anaconda I immediately made (and activated) a new environment "Sjobb20" and this is where I encountered the problem.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION: The problem was that sys.path did not include the correct path for finding the geopandas package. I ran `print(sys.path)` and noticed it did not point to my chosen environment. All paths listed were on the form:

`C:\\Users\\...\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin`

when the geopandas package was installed within the environment (testenv) as such:

```
C:\Users\...\anaconda3\envs\testenv\Lib\site-packages\geopandas
```

I added the appropriate path to sys.path by running the line:

```
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\...\anaconda3\envs\testenv\Lib\site-packages')
```

This worked and I can now run geopandas properly. I am currently working on permanently adding the environment path to sys.path so I won't have to do this every time.